# How is Apache Spark different from the Hadoop approach?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Everyone is saying that Spark is using the memory and because of that it's much faster than Hadoop.

I didn't understand from the Spark documentation what the real difference is.

- Where does Spark stores the data in memory while Hadoop doesn't?
- What happens if the data is too big for the memory? How similar would it be to Hadoop in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Spark tries to keep things in memory, whereas MapReduce keeps shuffling things in and out of disk.` Mean intermediate output store in main memory where as hadoop store intermediate result in secondary memory. MapReduce inserts barriers, and it takes a long time to write things to disk and read them back. Hence MapReduce can be slow and laborious. The elimination of this restriction makes Spark orders of magnitude faster. For things like SQL engines such as Hive, a chain of MapReduce operations is usually needed, and this requires a lot of I/O activity. On to disk, off of disk—on to disk, off of disk. When similar operations are run on Spark, Spark can keep things in memory without I/O, so you can keep operating on the same data quickly. This results in dramatic improvements in performance, and that means Spark definitely moves us into at least the interactive category. For the record, there are some benefits to MapReduce doing all that recording to disk — as recording everything to disk allows for the possibility of restarting after failure. If you’re running a multi-hour job, you don’t want to begin again from scratch. For applications on Spark that run in the seconds or minutes, restart is obviously less of an issue.

`It’s easier to develop for Spark`. Spark is much more powerful and expressive in terms of how you give it instructions to crunch data. Spark has a Map and a Reduce function like MapReduce, but it adds others like Filter, Join and Group-by, so it’s easier to develop for Spark.

```
Spark also adds libraries for doing things like machine learning, streaming, graph programming and SQL
```

Comment: What happens if the data is too big for the memory? How similar would it be to Hadoop in that case?

Comment: Spark do cache partial results (intermediate output not whole data)across the memory of its distributed workers, allowing for significantly faster/lower-latency computations. if intermediate data is not fit in memory in this case spark store intermediate data on disk

Comment: Spark lets you cache intermediate results in memory. Caching can dramatically improve performance if you have data structures that are used frequently, such as a lookup table or a matrix of scores in a machine-learning algorithm. Caching can also introduce problems since it will often require huge chunks of memory

Answer (score 5):

In Hadoop MapReduce the input data is on disk, you perform a **map** and a **reduce** and put the result back on disk. Apache Spark allows more complex pipelines. Maybe you need to **map** twice but don't need to **reduce**. Maybe you need to **reduce** then **map** then **reduce** again. The Spark API makes it very intuitive to set up very complex pipelines with dozens of steps.

You could implement the same complex pipeline with MapReduce too. But then between each stage you write to disk and read it back. Spark avoids this overhead when possible. Keeping data in-memory is one way. But very often even that is not necessary. One stage can just pass the computed data to the next stage without ever storing the whole data anywhere.

This is not an option with MapReduce, because one MapReduce does not know about the next. It has to complete fully before the next one can start. That is why Spark can be more efficient for complex computation.

The API, especially in Scala, is very clean too. A classical MapReduce is often a single line. It's very empowering to use.

Comment: To complete this answer: Spark uses a custom data structure named "Resilient Distributed Dataset", which can be explicitly stored in memory. If an RDD doesn't fit the memory, it is "spilled" to drives, in a graceful manner (i.e what cannot be put in memory goes to disks). Spark was initially conceived for iterative computations that play a (possibly) long pipeline of operations. Hadoop has to use tools such as Tez to orchestrate such a pipeline without having to go to disk back and forth.

Comment: Also Spark records transformations on RDDs as a DAG and can optimize that, which is alluded to in your answer about complex computation.